# What is a secure way to store sensitive data on a server running OpenVPN?

Tags: security, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi acting as both an OpenVPN server and an internal sftp backup server for my data. The VPN runs as a separate non-root user/group, which is different from my login that has the file permissions.

I would like to know if it is secure to have sensitive files on the same machine as a VPN sever or if I should separate them? Also, what would be the best way to secure the files on the server? Thanks for any advice; I'm pretty new at all this.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  Normally I would edit this a little to help you get the best answer, but I'm on my phone. I would consider rewriting the question to say something more along the lines of "What is a secure way to store sensitive data on a server running OpenVPN?"  You'll get better answers that way.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and advice KronoS!  I made the edits.